# Mongoose, Angular, Express PUT won't work

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to implement a simple edit function, and it won't work. My delete and get do work. I keep getting a 500 error on the put request. I have tried findIdAndUpdate and I hace tried FindOne as well. The error I get, is it fails to load the resource. But if I do a get request it works fine. If this makes a difference, the get request also returns a 304.

If I send the request in curl I get `TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;id&#39;`

Controller and Service

```
app.factory('gameService', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/games/:id', {id:'@id'},
        {'update': {method:'PUT'}}
    );
});

app.controller("gameController", function($scope, $http, gameService){
    $scope.games = [];
    $scope.newGame = {name: '', platform: ''};
    $scope.editMode = false;

$scope.games = gameService.query();

$scope.edit = function(game){
    $scope.editMode = true;
    $scope.newGame = gameService.get({id: game._id});
};

$scope.update = function(){
gameService.update({id: $scope.newGame._id}, function(response){
        $scope.games = gameService.query();
        $scope.newGame = {name: '', platform:''};
    });
    $scope.editMode = false;
};
});
```

API/Express/Mongoose

```
router.put('/games/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Game.findById(req.parms.id, function (err, game) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        game.name = req.body.name;
        game.platform = req.body.platform;
        game.save(function(err){
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({message:'Game Updated'});
        });
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<input required type="text" placeholder="Game Name" ng-model="newGame.name" /> <br/><br/>
<input required type="text" placeholder="Platform" ng-model="newGame.platform" /> <br/><br/>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Post" ng-click="post()" ng-hide="editMode" />
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Update" ng-click="update()" ng-show="editMode"/>
```

Model

```
var mongoose = require ('mongoose');
var GameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    platform: String
});

mongoose.model ('Game', GameSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.parms.id` should be `req.params.id` in your Mongoose/Express API route.

Comment: Fixed that. Now I have a new issue. game.save is clearing the name and platofmr fields. So it would appear req.body.name is not correct